# SEVERE: Invalid path was requested /actionname

Tags: java, struts-1, struts-config

In struts 1.3 whenever you see a invalid path was requested with /actioname exception in console

Comment: Probably there isn't an action with that path in the `struts-config.xml` file. You should include the error stacktrace and the struts-config.xml in your question.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have not yet configured any action tag in struts config file.

Answer (score -1):

please check your web.xml file.
ActionServlet should be configured